# How can I have multiple if statements in my expression builder?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm currently trying to have multiple if statements in my expression builder for multiple check boxes that I am ticking to alter the primary row data.

If I check block, the primary row of data changes to 0, from, say, 100.
If I also check prefer, it doubles the data, from 100 to 200.

Here's what I have so far:

```
IIf([block],0,[baseWeight]/329*100) +
IIf([prefer],[weightAfterPrefer]/329*100,[baseWeight]/329*100)
```

Currently, the '+'operator adds them both together and it's not working properly. It's doubling the data with this expression. I don't want the data to change unless I have a Yes/No box checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a second `IIf` into the True or False clause of the first `IIf`.
You didn't tell exactly how it should behave, but my guess would be this (formatted for readability):

```
IIf([block],
  0,
  IIf([prefer], [weightAfterPrefer]/329*100, [baseWeight]/329*100)
)
```